# Radiobutton click fails

Tags: javascript, radio-button, sapui5

I have implemented a Radio Button Group with three Radio Buttons. If I want to click on one Button to activate them, I have to click two times. The first time it only selects the box:

[image: see picture]

and the second time it selects the Radio Button.
Does anyone know an answer?

```
<VBox class="vbox_padding">
      <Label text="Graph" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop labelStyle" design="Bold"/>
      <RadioButton class="buttonPosition" id="rad_btn-1" groupName="column-group2" text="Number of User" selected="true"/>
      <RadioButton class="buttonPosition" id="rad_btn-2" groupName="column-group2" text="New Users"/>
      <RadioButton class="buttonPosition bottomButtonStyle" id="rad_btn-3" groupName="column-group2" text="Both"/>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: I mean in the question.

Comment: OK, your code fragment brought to life [on jsbin](https://jsbin.com/wubiyeyuhi/edit?html,output). I can't see any problems. Do you have more details? Perhaps you could expand the jsbin example?

Comment: I have the same problem in the UI5 Explored App: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.RadioButton/preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in SAPUI5.

As you said the bug is reproducable at [SAPUI5 Explored](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.RadioButton/preview) which runs SAPUI5 version 1.32.10 at the moment.

If you try [OpenUI5 Explored](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.RadioButton/preview) running OpenUI5 version 1.34.6 it works nicely.

In the [release notes](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#releasenotes.html) you find this entry for version 1.34.3:

**[FIX]** sap.m.RadioButton: Fixes an issue with clicking two times on a button to select it

As a workaround you could try to add the following css:

```
.sapMRb:focus:before {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```